# How do i create a shipment class object in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, php, shipment, object-manager, shipment-tracking

i am trying to get tracking from csv and save to magento 2 order programmatically.
i grabbed the create shipment & add tracking code from here https://www.scommerce-mage.com/blog/magento-2-how-to-create-shipment-programatically.html, and add an execute function (line 142) to load data from csv. but i'm not sure how to create an shipment object (line 179).

```
<?php
$file = fopen('track.csv', 'r', '"'); // set path to the CSV file
if ($file !== false)
{
    require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
    $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
    $objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
    $state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
    $state->setAreaCode('adminhtml');
    // add logging capability
    $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/import-update.log');
    $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);


    class ShipmentObject{
        /*There are two main functions 
        prepareShipment of \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ShipmentFactory class which prepare invoice and 
        addObject of \Magento\Framework\DB\TransactionFactory class which helps to create shipment and associate the shipment with original order in Magento 2.
        */

        /**
        * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment\TrackFactory
        */
        protected $_shipmentTrackFactory;

        /**
        * The ShipmentFactory is used to create a new Shipment.
        *
        * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ShipmentFactory
        */
        protected $_shipmentFactory;

        /**
         * @var \Magento\Framework\DB\TransactionFactory
         */
        protected $_transactionFactory;

        /**
        * @var \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface
        */
        protected $_orderRepository;

        protected $_file;
        /**
        * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment\TrackFactory $shipmentTrackFactory
        * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ShipmentFactory $shipmentFactory
        * @param \Magento\Framework\DB\TransactionFactory $transactionFactory
        * @param \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository
        */
        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment\TrackFactory $shipmentTrackFactory,
            \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ShipmentFactory $shipmentFactory,
            \Magento\Framework\DB\TransactionFactory $transactionFactory,
            \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
            \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory
            ) {
              $this->_shipmentTrackFactory = $shipmentTrackFactory;
              $this->_shipmentFactory = $shipmentFactory;
              $this->_transactionFactory = $transactionFactory;
              $this->_orderRepository = $orderRepository;
              $this->orderFactory = $orderFactory;
        }
        /**
         * @param int $orderId
         * @param string $trackingNumber
         * @return \Magento\Sales\Model\Shipment $shipment
         */
        protected function createShipment($orderId, $trackingNumber)
        {
            try {
                //$order = $this->_orderRepository->get($orderId); // this is increment id
                $order = $this->orderFactory->create()->loadByIncrementId($orderId);

                if ($order){
                    $data = array(array(
                        'carrier_code' => 'fedex', //$order->getShippingMethod(), //'carrier_code' => 'fedex', // need to lower case 
                        'title' => 'Federal Express', //$order->getShippingDescription(),   //'title' => 'Federal Express',  // how to set here 'Federal Express' or 'United Parcel Service'
                        'number' => $trackingNumber,                   //$trackingnumber,
                    ));         

                    $shipment = $this->prepareShipment($order, $data);
                    /*
                    if ($shipment) {
                        $order->setIsInProcess(true);
                        $order->addStatusHistoryComment('Automatically SHIPPED', false);
                        $transactionSave =  $this->_transactionFactory->create()->addObject($shipment)->addObject($shipment->getOrder());
                        $transactionSave->save();
                    }
                    */
                    if ($shipment) {
                       $order->setIsInProcess(true);
                       $order->addStatusHistoryComment('Automatically SHIPPED', false);
                       $transactionSave =  $this->_transactionFactory->create();
                       $transactionSave->addObject($shipment);
                       $transactionSave->addObject($shipment->getOrder());

                       $transactionSave->save();
                    }

                    //return $shipment; //original
                    //return $shipment->save(); //magefms
                    return $order; //helgeB
                }
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                    __($e->getMessage())
                );
            }
        }

        /**
        * @param $order \Magento\Sales\Model\Order
        * @param $track array
        * @return $this
        */
        protected function prepareShipment($order, $track)
        {
           $shipment = $this->_shipmentFactory->create(
               $order,
               $this->prepareShipmentItems($order),
               $track
           );
           return $shipment->getTotalQty() ? $shipment->register() : false;
        }

        /**
        * @param $order \Magento\Sales\Model\Order
        * @return array
        */
        protected function prepareShipmentItems($order)
        {
           $items = [];

           foreach($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
               $items[$item->getItemId()] = $item->getQtyOrdered();
           }
           return $items;
        }
        //after prepareShipmentItems function
        /**
        * @param $file
        */
        public function setFile($file)
        {
            $this->_file = $file;
        }

        /**
        * @param null
        * @return ordersave
        */
        public function execute()
        {
        // enter the number of data fields you require the product row inside the CSV file to contain

            $required_data_fields = 3;  //number of column in csv
            //$header = fgetcsv($file); // get data headers and skip 1st row

            while (($row = fgetcsv($this->_file, 100, ",")) !== FALSE)
            //while (($row = fgetcsv($file, 100, ",")) !== FALSE)   
            //while ( $row = fgetcsv($file, 100, ",") )   
            //while (($row = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE)
            {
                $data_count = count($row);
                if ($data_count < 1) {
                    continue;
                }

                $data = array();
                //$data = array_combine($header, $row);
                $data = array($row);

                $ponumber = $row[0]; //$data['ponumber']; // column A
                if ($data_count < $required_data_fields) {
                    $logger->info("Skipping Order Number " . $ponumber . ". Not enough data to import.");
                    continue;
                }
                //$shipvia = trim($data[1]); //trim($data['shipvia']);  // column B
                //$trackingnumber = trim($data[2]);//trim($data['trackingnumber']); // column C
                $shipvia = isset($row[1]) ? $row[1] : null;
                $trackingnumber =  isset($row[2]) ? $row[2] : null;

                switch ($shipvia) {
                    case "FEDEX":
                        $shipvia = "fedex";
                        break;
                    case "UPS":
                        $shipvia = "ups";
                        break;
                    case "USPS":
                        $shipvia = "usps";
                        break;
                    default:
                        $shipvia = "fedex";
                }

                ///////////////////////////////start adding tracking///////////////////////////////
                echo 'Updating Order: '.$ponumber.', with '.$shipvia.':'.$trackingnumber."\r\n";
                //print_r($row);

                $order = $this->createShipment($ponumber, $trackingnumber); /* @param int $orderId@param | @param string $trackingNumber */

                if ($order){   //HelgeB
                $order->save();
                }
                ///////////////////////////////end of  adding tracking///////////////////////////////   
                //magefms return $order->save();

            }// end of while loop

        }//end of execute function  

    } // end of class shipmentobject

    /**
    * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment\TrackFactory $shipmentTrackFactory
    * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ShipmentFactory $shipmentFactory
    * @param \Magento\Framework\DB\TransactionFactory $transactionFactory
    * @param \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository
    */
    $shipmentTrackFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment\TrackFactory');
    $shipmentFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ShipmentFactory');
    $transactionFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\DB\TransactionFactory');
    $orderRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface');
    $orderFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory');

    //create new class object
    $test = new ShipmentObject($shipmentTrackFactory,$shipmentFactory,$transactionFactory,$orderRepository,$orderFactory);
    $test->setFile($file);
    $test->execute();
    fclose($file); 
}// if file not exist, then do nothing
```

new error 
tracking information does not copy to (shipment tab) "sales_shipment_grid"

it is showing like this in admin panel, the shipment tab is empty, though the tracking is in there with no carrier assign.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to get the objects you need in the constructor of your `ShipmentObject` using the object manager and pass them as parameter.

Your code should look like this from line 175:

```
$shipmentTrackFactory = $objectManager->get('Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment\TrackFactory');
$shipmentFactory = $objectManager->get('Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ShipmentFactory');
$transactionFactory = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\DB\TransactionFactory');
$orderRepository = $objectManager->get('Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface');


$test = new ShipmentObject($shipmentTrackFactory,$shipmentFactory,$transactionFactory,$orderRepository);
```

But you will also have to pass the variable `$file` to the object in order to access it in the `execute` method. You can either extend the constructor and add a 5th parameter or implement a setter and call it like this:

```
protected $_file;
[...]
public function setFile($file)
{
    $this->_file = $file;
}
[...]
public function execute()
{
    [...]
    while (($row = fgetcsv($this->_file, 100, ",")) !== FALSE)
    [...]
}
[...]
$test = new ShipmentObject($shipmentTrackFactory,$shipmentFactory,$transactionFactory,$orderRepository);
$test->setFile($file);
$test->execute();
```

Update to your comment:

Change your method `createShipment` to return the order object if an order is found or false if not:

```
protected function createShipment($orderId, $trackingNumber)
{
    [...]
        if ($order){
        [...]
            return $order;
        }
        return false;
    [...]
}
```

Change your `execute` method to save the order only if an order object is returned and remove return inside the `execute` method:

```
public function execute()
    {
    [...]
        while (($row = fgetcsv($this->_file, 100, ",")) !== FALSE)
        {
        [...]
            $order = $this->createShipment($ponumber, $trackingnumber); /* @param int $orderId@param | @param string $trackingNumber */

            if ($order){   
                $order->save();
            }
        }// end of while loop

    }//end of execute function
```

Comment: Hi,thanks i'm still trying out the solution, but for now, the tracking number display in scientific notation like this "
Array
(
    [0] => 100007331
    [1] => FEDEX
    [2] => 4.90903E+11
)" how can i fix it?

Comment: The good part: Your code works, I'm sure the data comes that way from your input file. It looks like the original file was an Excel file with that kind of column formatting. Change the column format in the Excel file to text and check the data before you save it as csv.

Comment: it was mistake on my part, opened it using excel and re-saved it causing that error. it print the file correctly now, but it's not saving to magento order. can you help me check my execute function? i posted my updated code. Thank you.

Comment: i believe i call the correct function "createShipment" with the correct paremeters ($orderid & $trackingnumber) within the execute function, since the "createShipment" function will call "prepareShipment" then "prepareShipmentItems"

Comment: Your `createShipment`method must return the order object, because you call in your execute method `$order->save()` on the return of `createShipment`. And please remove the return keyword in your while loop in the `execute` method. I update also my answer with the changes in the two methods.

Comment: i update the code as you suggest. it does not throw any error. however, the tracking show up in the order view "information" tab, but not "shipment" tab ( screenshot above). do you know why is that?

Comment: It looks like your shipment has not been saved correctly. Please check the entries in tables `sales_shipment`, `sales_shipment_grid` and `sales_shipment_track` for that shipment. The data in the shipment tab comes from  `sales_shipment_grid` - it looks like the data is missing in that table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92208/discussion-between-kris-wen-and-helgeb).

Comment: I checked your code and inmho it should work: you add the shipment to the transaction, call save on the transaction which calls save on each added object including shipment. The copy process from `sales_shipment` to `sales_shipment_grid` is triggered in `sales_shipment_save_after` event. The only issue here can be that your cron is not running and you have enabled asynchronous indexing. Check your settings and see the documentation for that https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/sales/order-grid-updates-schedule.html

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue! I dont have cron enable for the test site, and asynchronous was enabled. By the way, do you know if i can move this file outside the magento root, i tried to change line 5 to "    require __DIR__ . '/public_html/app/bootstrap.php'; " and line 11 to "    $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/public_html/var/log/import-update.log');" but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: I have a similar question on updating the stock through a similar script. can you help me on this? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/270215/update-product-stock-quantity-programmatically-via-csv-loading-but-not-saving

Comment: Do you know How can I add some lines in this file to create invoice the same time as the shipment created. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

With the provided error, you can try to change this line

```
if ($shipment) {
   $order->setIsInProcess(true);
   $order->addStatusHistoryComment('Automatically SHIPPED', false);
   $transactionSave =  $this->_transactionFactory->create();
   $transactionSave->addObject($shipment);
   $transactionSave->addObject($shipment->getOrder());

   $transactionSave->save();
}
```

You should save objects in a separate line.

Comment: i have update the function with the lines you provided, but still getting error. can you see my updated codes error? i'm not sure if i use this function correctly. basically what i want to achieve is load the tracking number from csv file (#order,carrier,tracking) into magento2 order.

Comment: when you say load, you mean save tracking number from csv to magento sales order?

Comment: yes, save from csv to magento sales order. In the csv file i have 3 columns ( ordernumber, carrier, tracking), i want to save them to magento sales order.

Comment: in your execute function can you add a `return $order->save();`

Comment: added the line, still have the same error message.

Comment: in createShipment try return $shipment->save();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92168/discussion-between-magefms-and-kris-wen).

Comment: can you change `return $shipment;` to `return $order->save();`